# Moving orthographic camera with mouse drag

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm attempting to have a mouse click + drag result in the moving of the orthographic camera relative to the initial click.

What I have below is almost what I'd like for it to be.

However, you can tell that when I click on the area just south of the San Mateo Bridge in blue, the camera jumps to an odd location before allowing the camera to move smoothly throughout the drag.

[image]

All current manipulation of the camera is done through a class with an InputProcessor interface.

The methods that deal with the dragging of the camera are #touchDown and #touchDragged. #touchDragged takes into consideration the zoom of the map which is manipulated by #scrolled.

```
/**
 * Sets values at which mouse initially clicked to be used for moving the camera about
 *
 * @param screenX - The x coordinate, origin is in the upper left corner
 * @param screenY - The y coordinate, origin is in the upper left corner
 * @param pointer
 * @param button
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (button != 0) return false;
    pressedX = screenX;
    pressedY = screenY;
    return false;
}

/**
 * In the event of a drag, the camera position is altered to correspond to a drag relative to the initial click
 *
 * @param screenX - The x coordinate, origin is in the upper left corner
 * @param screenY - The y coordinate, origin is in the upper left corner
 * @param pointer
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    final float zoomMultiplier = camera.zoom / 20f;
    camera.position.set(map.getWidth() - screenX * zoomMultiplier, screenY * zoomMultiplier, 0);
    return false;
}

/**
 * Zooms into or out of the map based on which direction the user scrolls
 * @param amount - The intensity of the scroll
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    final float zoomAmount = amount * 1.15f;
    camera.zoom += zoomAmount;
    return false;
}
```

The zooming doesn't seem to affect the correctness of the dragging motion as it is taken into account. However, it seems that the initial click is not working as intended what with its initial jump and jumping into a seemingly random area for that matter.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `GestureDetector.GestureListener.pan`?

```
@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    camera.translate(deltaX, -deltaY, 0);
    camera.update();
    return false;
}
```

You still need to work with your zoom levels but if it's 1:1 this should drag the exact amount as the drag itself. However, it takes a bit of time/movement till `pan` is actually triggered.